# PostgreSQL trigger to update date modified

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am attempting to update the column `modified` whenever any of the fields are updated in the table `users` with a trigger in PostgreSQL version 13.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION
    myschema.on_users_update()
RETURNS
    TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified := NOW()
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_users_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON myschema.users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION on_users_update();
```

But I am getting the error `syntax error at or near "NEW"`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the previous line: the semicolon `;` at the end of the line was missed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION
    on_users_update()
RETURNS
    TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified := NOW();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

---

The exact error text will point to the error line:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW"
LINE 7:     RETURN NEW;
```

Due to the nature of syntax errors, it is always recommended to check the previous sentence. The syntactic parser usually cannot guess where someone forgot to complete the previous command and therefore shows an error from the point where it completely ceases to understand what was written.